# Can we compress PDF file size using iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, filesize

I am using iText to read and manipulate PDF files(reports). I read in a PDF report using iText and I save each page as a separate PDF file. But I am unable to reduce the size of the generated PDF. Is there any compression technique or any other way to reduce the size of the PDF? Does `pdfbox` help in this way?

Comment: There isn't much scope within a single page. Over a lot of pages there will be repeated fonts and text and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set a compression level when using iText:

```
Document document = ...
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
writer.setCompressionLevel(9);
```

Level 9 is slowest, but gives you the best compression available in iText.

---

Please note, that the compression effect largely depends on the PDF content. If your PDF file contains large binary streams, such as images, the compression will have little to no effect on your document. Also, iText will never compress XMP metadata stream regardless of the configuration options.

Comment: Still there is no effect

Comment: i used that compression what u mentioned.but there is no effect. pdf file is not compressed

Comment: Yes, it is not compressed!

Comment: I used `writer.SetFullCompression()` and it shrunk my file from 521kb to whopping 520kb. So it is not wokring that good. This was in C# though.

Comment: This answer is still not useful much but the code did reduce my PDF's size from 1.44 MB to a whopping 1.41 MB, somewhat similar to @Martin